# javascript failing to run in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to do something pretty basic as far as I'm concerned,

I have this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
jQuery.noConflict();
        var availableTags = <?php include('acname.php'); ?>;
        $("#department_name").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            autoFocus:true
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and this is the actual line that runs what it needs to for the textbox to have the autocomplete data:

```
<input type = "text" id = "department_name" name = "department_name" value = "" size="50" />
```

It works perfectly when outside of the modal but once it is in the popup modal it just fails to autocomplete, any advice here would be greatly appreciated! I have tried placing the code in the head but that didn't work, tried placing it basically inside the `<div>` of the modal but that also failed...

Comment: Can you make a stripped down jsfiddle? It likely needs to be initialized in the `shown.bs.modal` event instead of on page load.

Comment: Will try to make a jsfiddle a little later, but basically where would I put the script so it would work inside the modal popup? is there a specific place for this?

Comment: `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { // initialize autocomplete here })`